# Using Google Cloud Platform with a Compute Engine VM running a Ruby on Rails stack, how do I access the linked repository files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, automation, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud Platform with a Compute Engine VM running a Ruby on Rails stack.

I've connected a BitBucket repo to the VM.  Unfortunately, I do not see the files showing up anywhere on the VM when I SSH into it.

How do I access the linked repository files?

If I cannot access the files directly on the VM, then where can I find documentation that will tell me the correct way to access the Rails application from the VM?

Comment: What have you done so far, how did you configure the VM to work with BitBucket? You can visit https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-HowSSHandBitbucketworktogether for some more info (not sure how legitimate it is as I haven't worked with BitBucket but it's probably very similar to how you do it with GitHub). If you provide a little more info, might be able to help.

Comment: @Boyan Thanks.  BitBucket is really just a Git back-end.  What I need to know is now that I've linked this Git Repository to my Google Cloud account, how do I get the data on to the Compute Engine VM.  

I've set this up before my self on a Linux server using Gitolite (e.g. http://ruby-on-rails-dev.blogspot.com/2012/07/git-setup-gitolite.html) and then I setup a post-hook to move the source to a published area (e.g. http://ruby-on-rails-dev.blogspot.com/2012/07/git-setup-using-git-to-deploy.html).

I guess I'm asking "What is the correct way to push-to-deploy?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

connecting bitbucket or github in google cloud project doesn't do anything in VM instance.

If you want to access your repo inside your VM, you need to clone it.  Follow this steps

1. ssh to your VM
2. type `ssh-keygen` and follow instruction
3. Copy `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content
4. Now go to bitbucket. And add `ssh` key. In bitbucket, first go to `Manage Account` -> `SSH Keys` -> add new file and put the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content there.
5. now, clone the repo. `cd` it .

that's all.

Comment: thank you for the post.  I'm looking to automate this process. From a remote machine, is there a way I can push to the server and have that sync and deploy automatically (without installing programs like Gitolite)?

Comment: Your best option would be to use gcloud command . Trying to achieve this myself with gcloud .